# getting list of employee details based on a list of employee ids using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have an array of *employeeIds*, which is the primary key of the *Employee* table. I need to pass this array  and get the list of employee details. What can we be best query for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use

- [Query#setParameterList(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)
- and `IN` operator

Do something like

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Employee where empId in (:ids)");  
q.setParameterList("ids",empIds);  //empIds is an array of employee ids
q.list();
```

Comment: I am getting class cast exception. I have passing both List<Integer> as well as Integer[] as ids parameter. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @user2549538 : edit the question whatever you have tried? Right now I don't know, which part of code causes exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Employee object based based on the respective employeeId's . You can run a loop and inside loop you can fetch the respective object and save it in a list or somewhere else.

e.g :

```
// your array of employeeId's 
  int[] empIdList;
  List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>()

for(int i : empIdList)
{
  Employee emp = (Employee)session.get(Employee.class,i);
  empList.add(emp);
}
```